# Ubuntu 20.04 vulnerabilities fix

Tags: 20.04, vulnerability

I would like to know when these vulnerabilities will be fixed:

CVE-2020-6096
CVE-2020-1752

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The CVE-2020-6096 is not fixed yet in 20.04, because there is no upstream fix.

But it looks like a fix has been committed to `glibc` master branch.

[https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-6096.html](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-6096.html)

The CVE-2020-1752 doesn't affect 20.04.

[https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-1752.html](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-1752.html)

Comment: Sorry for my dumb questions but looking at https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-1752.html there are two packages involved eglibc and glibc. For Ubuntu 20.04 eglibc says DNE and for  glibc not-affected. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as base docker image for our components so my questions: 1) What is the meaning of DNE. 2) What are the difference between this two packages? They are both used in ubuntu 20.04 standard docker image?

Comment: DNE means doesn't exist. Only `glibc` exists in 20.04.